# How are temperature changes implemented in a molecular dynamics simulations?

Tags: temperature, simulations, molecular-dynamics

Molecular dynamics simulations are always associated with a temperature that represents the natural state of a system.

However, some techniques, like Simulated Annealing Molecular Dynamics, where temperature fluctuates up and down to allow the system to escape local minima, use a non-constant temperature.

In such a case, how is this applied to the system?

I found a very [closely related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/432470/how-do-we-take-temperature-into-account-in-ab-initio-molecular-dynamics-simulati), but the answer goes beyond my knowledge. If I am looking at Langevin dynamics, is it accurate to say that the temperature is being applied primarily as an increase in particle acceleration?

Comment: Matter Modeling SE is full of experts on this.

Comment: @JonCuster Got it, thanks! I've reposted there!